# http: how to get json from batch response?

Tags: javascript, json, http, xmlhttprequest, fetch

How do you get json from batch request?

I'm getting the following error if I console.log my `fetch response.json()`:

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 3`

If I dive into network sources to see the response `(by the way it has status 200)` in devTools I see the following line producing the error:

```
--batch_SuWHKrAohxj1o_r1qo6yzaAu-gfaqQ1p <-- producing error. Red lines underneath.
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer

{
..........
..........
.........
}
```

My `fetch()` call has following headers:

```
  headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
  headers.append('Host', 'www.googleapis.com');
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/mixed; boundary="deel_foo"');
  headers.append('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip');
  headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
```

```
fetch(.....).then(response) => response.json())
```

each batch request inside body has `Content-Type: application/json`

EDIT:
I want the following response.

```
// stripped off the following:
--batch_K_aZ7aQTR91ApoeMUayvTEJhZBs6PW9n
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer
// stripped off till here.
{   // I want this part, as it's valid JSON.
  "id": "17vegjeogjeogje44",
  "threadId": "17vjorgjerogjerogjer",
  "labelIds": [
    "CATEGORY_UPDATES",
    "INBOX"
  ],
  "snippet": "Don&#39;t miss this idea and many more. Stash what matters to you and inspire others. \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c",
  "payload": {
    "partId": "",
    "mimeType": "text/html",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
........
etc
........
etc........
}
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected ... in JSON at position ...` means you're trying to parse something as JSON that is not JSON. Print the `.text()` of the response to the console to have a look at what you actually get from the server.

Comment: @Tomalak if i log `.text()` I see header part included in response. `--batch_K_aZ7aQTR91ApoeMUayvTEJhZBs6PW9n
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer` 
Is there a way to "strip off" this part so I get the json part? I will update my question to clarify.

Comment: So apparently you get a multipart response from the server. What's the main `Content-Type` the server sends?

Comment: @Tomalak My knowledge is lacking to determine the main `Content-type`. But I see two  Content-Type defined in the response, application/http and application/json. The body (the part between brackets { }, is valid json).

Comment: *"Is there a way to "strip off" this part so I get the json part?"* - I would recommend a multipart parser (look around for a ready-to-use library), but if you want to do it manually, the MIME spec states that headers and body are separated by a double CR+LF. So you could split the response text at `'\r\n\r\n'` and then take the part you need. Multiple individual parts of the response are separated by the boundary (e.g. `--batch_K_aZ7aQTR91ApoeMUayvTEJhZBs6PW9n` in your case), the boundary is a random string defined in the main `Content-Type` header of the response.

Comment: ...alternatively, look at the documentation of the API you're using and there might be a way to tell it that you're not interested in multipart responses. This feels like one of those "if it's hard, you're probably doing something wrong" types of issues. Having to parse multipart data is a rather odd problem on the client end.

Comment: @Tomalak thank you. I will google for a multipart parser and determine if I will use it or manually format the data with string/array methods. And sorry made a mistake. I discovered there are indeed `--batch_K_aZ7aQTR91ApoeMUayvTEJhZBs6PW9` seperators and `headers` inside the body which I pressumed to be all valid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else faces same issue:

I thought there was singular response with a body containing JSON. Technically there is a singular response but it's formatted as multiple responses.

Multipart responses actually contain multiple http responses each with an `header` and seperator `--[foobar]`. They aren't all concatenated inside a containing body and it needs to be manually tranformed into useable data by applying string/array methods or using a library.

There is no in-build solution for this equivalent to `response=>response.json()`.